# Move part of computation to GPU?

Tags: android, optimization

I have a complex algorithm, which takes significant time to compute. It is easily parallelizable though. One part of the algorithm is FFT for example. Is there a way to move some part of the computation to GPU instead of CPU on Android ?

Comment: I have my doubts about whether this is possible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9005352/how-to-use-opencl-on-android

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12336862/is-it-possible-to-program-gpu-for-android