# OpenCV: using GPU on android

Tags: android, opencv, gpu

A simple question: can i use gpu to render some informations, like rotating a matrix or apply filters to a bitmap?

I really want to speed up things a little...

Using openCV 2.4.11 and android studio 1.5

Comment: afaik gpgpu on mobile devices is most often done by glsl. Afaik, OpenCV does not use glsl for gpgpu tasks afaik. only cuda and openCL are used and some platform optimized things like in openCV4Tegra

Comment: Hum... So it cant be done?  Is there anything to speed up the processing?

Comment: you could implement it yourself

Comment: But using wat strategy?? What methods??

Comment: you'll have to transform your general tasks to rendering tasks. See http://www.mathematik.uni-dortmund.de/~goeddeke/gpgpu/tutorial.html and http://www.computer-graphics.se/gpu-computing/2a.pdf for example. Keywords if you want to search on is "gpgpu"

Comment: and maybe http://gpgpu.org/tag/android

Comment: have a look at this, too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12336862/is-it-possible-to-program-gpu-for-android